# How can I get posted data passed along when the user is first redirected through Paypal?

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been trying to tackle this for some time now. I have an order page where the customer must enter information like name, address, etc. and some more unique fields. I have set up IPN with Paypal and the customer is redirected to the page I specified. But the data does not come along with it. I hope I'm asking my question properly so that I don't get "closed." Here is the HTML in the Paypal submit button that redirects to their page.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="NT2YC6LP7SWBE">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<input type="hidden" name="child_name" id="child_name" value ="<? echo $child_name; ?>" maxlength="20"/>
<input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" value ="<? echo $age; ?>" maxlength="4"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hometown" id="hometown" value ="<? echo $hometown; ?>" maxlength="32"/>
<input type="hidden" name="boy_girl" id="boy_girl" value ="<? echo $boy_girl; ?>" maxlength="4"/>
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" id="first_name" value ="<? echo $first_name; ?>" maxlength="32"/>
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" id="last_name" value ="<? echo $last_name; ?>" maxlength="32"/>
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value ="<? echo $email; ?>" maxlength="64"/>
<input type="hidden" name="address1" id="address1" value ="<? echo $address1; ?>" maxlength="64"/>
<input type="hidden" name="address2" id="address2" value ="<? echo $address2; ?>" maxlength="32"/>
<input type="hidden" name="city" id="city" value ="<? echo $city; ?>" maxlength="32"/>
<input type="hidden" name="state" id="state" value ="<? echo $state; ?>" maxlength="20"/>
<input type="hidden" name="zip" id="zip" value ="<? echo $zip; ?>" maxlength="10"/>
<input type="hidden" name="country" id="country" value ="<? echo $country; ?>" maxlength="32"/>
<input type="hidden" name="payment_type" id="payment_type" value ="paypal" maxlength="6"/>
<input type="hidden" name="paid" id="paid" value ="yes" maxlength="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="mailed" id="mailed" value ="no" maxlength="3"/>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

It has been pointed out to me that some of the variables are not "Paypal variables" and I can fix that later, but none of my data is making it back to my specified page after visiting Paypal, even the variables that Paypal supports like "city." Here is the PHP that I have on the page that they get redirected to.

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    // error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        $child_name = htmlentities($_POST['child_name']);
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $hometown = $_POST['hometown'];
        $boy_girl = $_POST['boy_girl'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $first_name = htmlentities($_POST['first_name']);
        $last_name = htmlentities($_POST['last_name']);
        $address1 = htmlentities($_POST['address1']);
        $address2 = htmlentities($_POST['address2']);
        $city = htmlentities($_POST['city']);
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $zip = htmlentities($_POST['zip']);
        $country = htmlentities($_POST['country']);
        $payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
        $paid = $_POST['paid'];
        $mailed = $_POST['mailed'];
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
}       

        $query = "INSERT INTO customer_list (
        number, child_name, age, hometown, boy_girl, first_name, last_name, email,
        address1, address2, city, state, zip, country, payment_type, paid, mailed)
        VALUES ('', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($child_name)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($age)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($hometown)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($boy_girl)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($first_name)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($last_name)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($address1)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($address2)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($city)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($state)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($zip)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($country)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($payment_type)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($paid)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($mailed)."')";
            if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

                $subject = "Thank You for Your Order";
                $message = "Thank you for placing your order with My-Letter-From-Santa-Claus.com. \n\nYou can expect to receive your personalized letter soon. Please make note of your customer number. Your customer number is: ".mysql_insert_id().". \n\nPlease send all inquiries to : info@my-letter-from-santa-claus.com";
                $from = "info@my-letter-from-santa-claus.com";
                $headers = "From:" . $from;
                mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
                echo 'Thank you for your order.';
                echo 'Letter For '.$child_name;
            } else {
                echo mysql_error();
            }
```

I copied most of it directly from x.com except for changing to my own variables of course. Nothing is getting posted to the database but that's not the issue since I cannot even echo the data. A couple things are being entered into the database but it's not the data from my order page - it is the first name and last name that is entered as the credit card info on Paypal, and for payment_type it says "instan" (I maxed it at 6 characters) but as you can see from the hidden input field in the HTML, I wanted to post the value "paypal." How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

are you using the Paypal Sandbox for testing? If not, I strongly recommend it: https://developer.paypal.com/, and the manual: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf.

I don't see the field name="business" in you code. That is the field which Paypal uses to identify you seller account. But maybe it only has to do with the "cmd" parameter (I use _xclick).

Here is a set of fields which works at this time for me, maybe it helps you:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/de/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_email_here">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="ipn_url_here">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="redirect_url">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="redirect_if_cancelled_url">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="number_of_items">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="product_name">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="product_number">
```

Comment: I tested it live. I did not use the business parameter, but I doubt that is the nature of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using a hosted button.  You can't include custom stuff in the general HTML for those.  The only custom fields that can be included have to be done in the PayPal button creation wizard.

You also need to make sure you're not confusing IPN and PDT.  If you simply want data to come back to your return URL that the user is sent to after completing payment that would be PDT.  It's not recommended that you handle post-order-processing with this, though, because there is no guarantee the user will make it there.

IPN can be used for that because it will be triggered no matter what, but again, that's totally separate from your checkout and PDT.

I would highly recommend using Express Checkout instead of standard buttons since you seem to be familiar with PHP, too.  I've got a [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/) that makes this very simple for you, and I can provide 30 min of free training if you need it, which is generally more than enough to get people up-and-running as long as you understand PHP and how to work with array data.

You can do it with Standard, too, but you'd have to move away from using a hosted button @AndreiHardau is showing.  That would allow you to include [additional fields](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) like address1, address2, address_overide, etc, and those fields would then be returned in IPN, PDT, and in GetTransactionDetails.

Comment: I downloaded your library. Which of the PHP files would be appropriate for what I am trying to do?

Comment: @CTViking If you want to go with Express Checkout you'd end up using SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails (optionally), and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  Let me know if you'd like to schedule a free 30 min training session and I can walk you through the steps.

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly nice to offer to train me for 30 min. Hopefully we can square this away with a few short exchanges without me taking up 30 minutes of your time. I read through SetExpressCheckout in addition to the 2 files it requires. It's quite extensive with several details that are irrelevant to what I need. IF you can take a moment, please go to my sites's order screen http://my-letter-from-santa-claus.com/order.php and look at my fields. When they are filled out and the user clicks submit they are directed to a page that gives the option of paying either by mail ..........

Comment: ...... or by Paypal. If they pay by mail. They are then directed to a printable page and all that data is saved to the SQL database. However if they choose Paypal they go to the Paypal page, pay, and then get redirected to the page I specified. But the data they entered does not come along with it.

Comment: @CTViking Yeah, there is a bunch of stuff in there you wouldn't need, but you would just leave those parameters blank and fill in the stuff you do need.  I think you'd like it better in the long run, as it's much less restricting.  I updated the answer with some more details about doing this with Standard, though.

Comment: Regarding your edit, are you suggesting I use AndreiHardau's button type or not? I'm a little confused by the way you wrote it. And don't I need to use the button I copy from Payal - even if I add some hidden input fields to it?

Comment: I always recommend using Express Checkout if it's something you think you can handle.  It just gives you more freedom to make your integration exactly what you need.  If you want to stick with Standard button code, though, you can make it work, but you'll have to use a non-hosted button like the sample @Andrei Hardau posted.