# return facility in paypal button not working

Tags: php, html, paypal

I am trying to send passthrough data in a paypal paynow button and have paypal return that data to my php page when user clicks “return to merchant” button after paying.

For this I am using the “return” facility in the paypal button, together with rm=2 to send all the data back as post. However, I cannot get it to work. Here is my paypal button html:

```
<form name="paypal2" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"     method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxx">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="testinvoice_fromcode2">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="testcustom_fromcode1">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="yes"><!--agreetc-->
<input type="hidden" name="os0" value="<?php echo $aid; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="os1" value="<?php echo $agent; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value=http://www.example.com/Admin/conpanel/privat/phpvendorpaidad.php>
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input id="submit" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

In the IPN notification, paypal renders:
os0 as option_selection1,
os1 as option_selection2,
on0 as option_name1,
on1 as option_name2,

I know that on0 and os0 are supposed to be used as name value pairs but way back in 2009 when I first wrote this script there were only 2 sets allowed and therefore I used all 4 to carry values and it worked then.

But essentially, I cannot  understand why

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value=http://www.example.com/Admin/conpanel/privat/phpvendorpaidad.php>
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
```

is not working.

I cannot pick up these values in the receiving script, phpvendorpaidad.php, either as

```
$aid=$_REQUEST['option_selection1'];
```

or as

```
$aid=$_REQUEST['os0'];
```

for example.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Much appreciated.

I also have an IPN listener page that is working normally. Could another way be to build this in to the IPN listener page using javascript to send the form data automatically on page onload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is paypal actually POSTing to your return script or using GET? In the latter case, you can see the txn_id and some other info in the query string, but you will NOT get the whole payment detail data.

If you have Auto Return set to On (meaning the user get automatically redirected back to your site, without having to click a button), then paypal with send a GET request and will include only a few items.

var_dump($_REQUEST) and var_dump($_POST) in your script to see what you are getting.

Comment: many thanks for your help. I have tried everything, with and without Auto Return and PDT. As you say, I get GET transfers (with query-strings) with Auto Return/PDT on and POST transfers with these off. I have noted the urls and var_dump($_REQUEST) in all cases but Paypal is POSTing nothing to my return script (ie Return to Merchant). The strange thing is that this was all working when I first wrote the scripts in 2009. The buttons are still from that time.

Comment: I have wasted so much time on this that now I think I will try POSTing the variables from my IPN handling/listening script using javascript form submit. The IPN handling script is functioning ok and payments are being successfully made (VERIFIED & COMPLETED) and all payment data being emailed to me.

Comment: JBart, YOU ARE BRILLIANT! I just discovered that I had inadvertently left 'rm=0' in my script modified code (I did this during testing different ways). Returning to 'rm-2' successfully POSTed all payment details, which I was able to see thanks to your suggestion re var_dump($_REQUEST). The POSTed data are inside an array so I will have to extract them out of the array to get to the ones I want. MANY, MANY THANKS ONCE AGAIN!!!

Comment: The only strange thing is that in 2009 I was able to access the data I required without having to extract them out of an array, at least this is what my receiving script is showing. I wonder if Paypal has made changes

Comment: Re my comment above, my 2009 return/receiving script shows that I was getting on0, os0, on1, os1 as GET data, so must have come over from Paypal as query-strings, and hence I did not have to extract them out of an array. I am trying to remember how I set Paypal up to do this, or maybe Paypal has changed so that this is no longer possible. As you write, with Auto Return on only a few data items get sent.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem lay in defective if/else logic in my return code, which was set up in 2009 to handle the GET variables that Paypal was sending to the return script in those days. This logic had to differentiate between the POSTed data received from a preceeding form on my server and the GET data received from Paypal. Paypal appears to have chenged since 2009 and no longer sends GET data to the return script but POST data via

```
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value=http://www.example.com/Admin/conpanel/privat/phpvendorpaidad.php>
 <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
```

Once this was corrected the program worked.

However, I was only able to discover the problem thanks to the brilliant suggestion from JBart to var_dump($_REQUEST) (or the more easily read print_r($_REQUEST)). Without this I would still have been floundering. So cheers JBart, would love to buy you a drink if you are in the neighbourhood (NW London)!

And no, I didn't need to extract any variables from the received POSTed array (see my last comment above), just normal '$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];'. In this I had misinterpreted another thread on the subject in "[How can I get posted data passed along when the user is first redirected through Paypal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351072/how-can-i-get-posted-data-passed-along-when-the-user-is-first-redirected-through?rq=1)"